# how to join one table to multiple other tables

Tags: sql, sybase

i have a query which is used to generate reports. There are multiple fields to be displayed. One requirement is such that i need to join one table to different tables with different aliases for data. e.g., table 1 employee id with employee table for knowing the full name. similarly table 2 employee id with employee table for table 2 employee id full name. PFB the query:

```
    select * from office o
    left join employee e
    on e.id=o.id
    left join master m
    on m.id=o.id
    left join student s1
    on e.id=s1.id
    left join student s2
    on m.id=s2.id
```

Can we optimize this query to use only one join statement of student table instead of multiple table join statement? I need to reduce the number of tables used in the query since i'm getting the error as too many tables in the query maximum allowed is 50. Please help. Appreciate.

Comment: add your data schema

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database.  Please specify product and version as it can affect answers.

Comment: Might i ask why there are so many tables? Are you able to redesign the database? Your snippit suggests multiple different tables with the same data

Comment: There is no way this query works - `office.id = employee.id = master.id = student.id` in the `JOIN` conditions you wrote.  Post the actual schema of each table involved.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we optimize this query to use only one join statement of student
>   table instead of multiple table join statement?

No, I would not call it query optimization.  However, for reporting purposes you reduce the joins by creating views.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315714.htm